# How to verify downloaded file with .sig file?

Tags: shell, command-line, command, signature, verify

When I download GCC, it also has a `.sig` file, and I think it is provided to verify downloaded file.
(I downloaded GCC from [here](http://ftp.kaist.ac.kr/gnu/gnu/gcc/gcc-4.7.2/)).

But I can't figure out how should I use it. I tried `gpg`, but it complains about public key.

```
[root@localhost src]# gpg --verify gcc-4.7.2.tar.gz.sig gcc-4.7.2.tar.gz
gpg: Signature made Thu 20 Sep 2012 07:30:44 PM KST using DSA key ID C3C45C06
gpg: Can't check signature: No public key
[root@localhost src]#
```

How can I verify downloaded file with `.sig` file?

Answer (score 111):

You need to import public key: `C3C45C06`

Can be done in three steps.

1. find public key ID:

   ```
   $ gpg gcc-4.7.2.tar.gz.sig 
   gpg: Signature made Čt 20. září 2012, 12:30:44 CEST using DSA key ID C3C45C06
   gpg: Can't check signature: No public key
   ```
2. import the public key from key server. It's usually not needed to choose key server, but it can be done with `--keyserver <server>`. [Keyserver examples.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_server_%28cryptographic%29#Keyserver_examples)

   ```
   $ gpg --recv-key C3C45C06
   gpg: requesting key C3C45C06 from hkp server keys.gnupg.net
   gpg: key C3C45C06: public key "Jakub Jelinek <jakub@redhat.com>" imported
   gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
   gpg: Total number processed: 1
   gpg:               imported: 1
   ```

If the command error's out with a timeout, [you may be behind a firewall that is blocking the default gpg port. Try using the `--keyserver' option with port 80](https://serverfault.com/questions/168826/how-to-install-gpg-keys-from-behind-a-firewall) (almost all firewalls allow port 80 b/c of web browsing):

```
$ gpg --keyserver hkp://${HOSTNAME}:80 --recv-keys ${KEY_ID}
```

3. verify signature:

   ```
   $ gpg gcc-4.7.2.tar.gz.sig 
   gpg: Signature made Čt 20. září 2012, 12:30:44 CEST using DSA key ID C3C45C06
   gpg: Good signature from "Jakub Jelinek <jakub@redhat.com>" [unknown]
   gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
   gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
   Primary key fingerprint: 33C2 35A3 4C46 AA3F FB29  3709 A328 C3A2 C3C4 5C06
   ```

The output should say "Good signature".

---

> gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!

Is for another question ;)

Comment: In the case that the file requiring verification is gnupg (not in the question), SHA-1 check-sums are available on the gnupg site for verifying ones first gnupg download.

Comment: During signature verification, gpg processes the tarball file and its corresponding .sig file as a unit.  If the tarball is missing or renamed, gpg provides the opportunity to specify the tarball name.

Comment: I have get an RSA key, and doesn't to work without or with `--keyserver` from that list, only one get it but it seems not trusted, its weird since I'm trying it on `GNU coreutils` that is a widely used package.

Comment: also, if gpg warns "no command supplied, guessing what you mean", use `gpg --verify gcc-4.7.2.tar.gz.sig` instead.

Comment: So, I presume this is better than just a hash of the file - but I'm not sure how - given that "There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner."

Answer (score 32):

This other avenue is particularly useful for verifying GNU projects (e.g. [Octave](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/octave/)) since the key requested by their signature may not be found in any key server.

From https://ftp.gnu.org/README

> There are also .sig files, which contain detached GPG signatures of
> the above files, automatically signed by the same script that
> generates them.
>
> You can verify the **signatures for gnu project files** with the keyring
> file from:
>
> https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gnu-keyring.gpg
>
> In a **directory with the keyring file, the source file to verify and
> the signature file**, the command to use is:
>
> `$ gpg --verify --keyring ./gnu-keyring.gpg foo.tar.xz.sig`

Comment: But if we are talking about security then it is better to use HTTPS connection: [https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gnu-keyring.gpg](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gnu-keyring.gpg)

Comment: Funny, I'm here explicitly to figure how to validate Octave! :)

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't find the Bash maintainer's key in any key server but this was what I needed to verify the signature for its source code.

Comment: For octave see the answer about gpg4win app here: https://superuser.com/questions/1268544/how-to-verify-a-download-file-using-a-sig-file-and-public-key-in-windows-10

Answer (score 2):

You have to search the public keyservers for the given key id: in your case `ID C3C45C06`
Import the found key in your local keystore and after this the verification should be OK.
I use Ubuntu 12.04 and it comes with Seahorse key management software. Before the key import I was seeing this:

```
~/Downloads$ gpg --verify --keyring ./gnu-keyring.gpg icecat-31.5.0.en-US.linux-x86_64.tar.bz2.sig icecat-31.5.0.en-US.linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
gpg: Signature made  9.03.2015 (пн) 22,35,52 EET using RSA key ID D7E04784
gpg: Can't check signature: public key not found
```

After the key import I was seeing this:

```
~/Downloads$ gpg --verify --keyring ./gnu-keyring.gpg icecat-31.5.0.en-US.linux-x86_64.tar.bz2.sig icecat-31.5.0.en-US.linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
gpg: Signature made  9.03.2015 (пн) 22,35,52 EET using RSA key ID D7E04784
gpg: Good signature from "Ruben Rodriguez (GNU IceCat releases key) <ruben@gnu.org>"
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: A573 69A8 BABC 2542 B5A0  368C 3C76 EED7 D7E0 4784
```

Comment: Opened a question about this warning at https://superuser.com/questions/1616531/gpg4win-signature-validation-how-to-fix-warning-this-key-is-not-certified-wit

Answer (score -2):

according to this http://gcc.gnu.org/mirrors.html that should be Jakub Jelinek and valid. i don't know where you would get his public key though.