# How to Install gcc 5.3 with yum on CentOS 7.2?

Tags: gcc, installation, centos7, yum, gcc5

I am using CentOS 7.2

When I use `yum groupinstall "Development Tools"`, gcc version is 4.8.5, like this:

[image]

I would like to install gcc 5.3

How to approach this with `yum`?

Comment: follow this tutorial https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-gcc-on-centos-6

Comment: @MohammadShahadatHossain  Is there a `yum` resource anywhere?

Comment: I am not sure but In this case you can use RPM resource from here. https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=gcc

Comment: devtoolset now provides 5.3.1 -- see my answer below for the commands to enable and install it using yum.

Answer (score 233):

**Update:**
Often people want the most recent version of gcc, and devtoolset is being kept up-to-date, so maybe you want devtoolset-N where N={4,5,6,7...}, check yum for the latest available on your system).  Updated the cmds below for N=7.

There is a package for gcc-7.2.1 for devtoolset-7 as an example.  First you need to enable the [Software Collections](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/devtoolset-4/), then it's available in devtoolset-7:

```
sudo yum install centos-release-scl
sudo yum install devtoolset-7-gcc*
scl enable devtoolset-7 bash
which gcc
gcc --version
```

Comment: the gcc version in devtoolset has in the mean time been bumped to 5.3.1

Comment: Not only that, but you can install devtoolset-6 to get 6.2.1

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day! Also, I see that my /usr/bin/c++ is still linked to gcc 4.8.5, so I had to relink to gcc 6: `ln -sf /opt/rh/devtoolset-6/root/usr/bin/g++ /usr/bin/c++`

Comment: changing the symlink isn't the best thing to do, since it's probably owned/managed by another package that could get upgraded.  It's better to activate it in your login, or in the system-wide login script with `scl enable devtoolset-6 bash` or `. /opt/rh/devtoolset-6/bin/enable` [updated link to software tools docs](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/devtoolset-6/)

Comment: Running `yum install devtoolset-4-binutils` might be helpful as well to get complete GCC toolchain.

Comment: I used `source scl_source enable devtoolset-4` to switch my current gcc with the one installed by `devtoolset-4`

Comment: Use devtoolset-6, because [devtoolset-4 is End of life](https://wiki.centos.org/SpecialInterestGroup/SCLo/CollectionsList).

Comment: `devtoolset-6` now has `gcc 6.3.1`

Comment: I see 4,6,7 on mine. Why no 5?

Comment: Just do a `yum install devtoolset-8` without anything after that.  The devtoolset-N packages are meta packages that install the default packages and pull in the necessary dependencies

Comment: this answer doesn't work any more, it installs gcc 7

Comment: This answer still works, it's up to you to choose the right version of devtoolset to install.

Comment: How can I use g++7 as default, when I open a new terminal, it is still v4.8.5

Comment: you need to `scl enable devtoolset-7 bash` every time you open a new shell, or add it to your *rc

Comment: devtoolset-5 does not exists on centos7 hence the answer does not apply to the op question.

Comment: I installed devtoolset-9 but this does nothing at all... /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 is still the ancient version. The libstdc++.so inside devtoolset-9 is just a few characters that links back to the useless /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6. Turns out you have to use podman to do anything with c++ in devtoolset, but I can't because I'm already operating inside a docker container and so podman can't do jack. So this whole piece of crap OS is useless.

Comment: It could work for me. The system still use the old version of gcc placed on the directory /usr/bin/gcc.

Comment: The procedure on RHEL7 is similar but more painful. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72002572/1569204

Comment: @Fafaman - there is inconsistency in versions, actually devtoolset-4 contains gcc 5.3.1, and dev-toolset-5 doesn't exist.

Comment: Needed this for effective: `source /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/enable;`

Answer (score 78):

**Update:** Installing latest version of gcc 9: ([**gcc 9.3.0**](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-9.3.0/)) - released **March 12, 2020**:

Same method can be applied to gcc 10 ([**gcc 10.1.0**](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-10.1.0/)) - released **May 7, 2020**

**Download file:** [gcc-9.3.0.tar.gz](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-9.3.0/gcc-9.3.0.tar.gz) or
[gcc-10.1.0.tar.gz](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-10.1.0/gcc-10.1.0.tar.gz)

**Compile and install:**

```
//required libraries: (some may already have been installed)
dnf install libmpc-devel mpfr-devel gmp-devel

//if dnf install libmpc-devel is not working try:
dnf --enablerepo=PowerTools install libmpc-devel

//install zlib
dnf install zlib-devel*

./configure --with-system-zlib --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++

make -j 8 <== this may take around an hour or more to finish
              (depending on your cpu speed)

make install
```

*Tested under [CentOS 7.8.2003](http://linux.darkpenguin.net/distros/CentOS/7.8.2003/isos/x86_64/) for gcc 9.3 and gcc 10.1*

*Tested under [CentOS 8.1.1911](http://centos.mirrors.proxad.net/8.1.1911/isos/x86_64/) for gcc 10.1* (may take more time to compile)

**Results:** gcc/g++ 9.3.0/10.1.0

[image]
[image]

**Installing gcc 7.4** [(gcc 7.4.0)](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-7.4.0/) - released **December 6, 2018**:

**Download file:** https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-7.4.0/gcc-7.4.0.tar.gz

**Compile and install:**

```
//required libraries:
yum install libmpc-devel mpfr-devel gmp-devel

./configure --with-system-zlib --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++

make -j 8 <== this may take around 50 minutes or less to finish with 8 threads
              (depending on your cpu speed)


make install
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Notes:**

**1.** [This Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331015/how-to-verify-downloaded-file-with-sig-file) will help to see how to verify the downloaded source file.

**2.** Use the option `--prefix` to install gcc to another directory other than the default one. The toplevel installation directory defaults to /usr/local. [Read about gcc installation options](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html)

Comment: Why download from ftp.mirrorservice.org rather than  ftp.gnu.org? You should also download and verify the corresponding `.sig` file (the pgp signature).

Comment: Configuring as shown without --prefix will install in /usr/local/ which may or may not come ahead of your original gcc installation on PATH

Comment: `make -j $(nproc)`

Comment: This took me over 4 hours to compile and more than 6gb of HDD space.

Comment: As tim18 suggested, is it safe to run `make && make install` without `--prefix`? If do so, everything is installed into `/usr/` not even `/usr/local`, check the `config.log`: `Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info ...`

Comment: Note that you will not be able to put binaries compiled with a gcc compiled in this way into an RPM (at least with the default RPM environment).  I needed to add `--enable-linker-build-id` before that would work.

Comment: this answers other question

Comment: @StepanYakovenko: My answer includes installing gcc 5.3 but I deleted it recently because no one will search to install an old gcc version, and this method still work for that if some one needs it.

Comment: use ftp://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/gcc/gcc-5.3.0/gcc-5.3.0.tar.bz2 if you want gcc 5.3

Comment: @HDJEMAI - Could you please help me on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61831832/angular-material-group-and-expand-rows-based-on-id-column

Answer (score 14):

You can use the centos-sclo-rh-testing repo to install GCC v7 without having to compile it forever, also enable V7 by default and let you switch between different versions if required.

```
sudo yum install -y yum-utils centos-release-scl;
sudo yum -y --enablerepo=centos-sclo-rh-testing install devtoolset-7-gcc;
echo "source /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/enable" | sudo tee -a /etc/profile;
source /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/enable;
gcc --version;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.

Comment: Sadly this solution does not update the `/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so` file to have the newer symbols.

Answer (score 7):

The best approach to use yum and update your devtoolset is to utilize the CentOS SCLo RH Testing repository.

```
yum install centos-release-scl-rh
yum --enablerepo=centos-sclo-rh-testing install devtoolset-7-gcc devtoolset-7-gcc-c++
```

Many additional packages are also available, to see them all

```
yum --enablerepo=centos-sclo-rh-testing list devtoolset-7*
```

You can use this method to install any dev tool version, just swap the 7 for your desired version. devtoolset-6-gcc, devtoolset-5-gcc etc.

Answer (score 0):

this guide helped me:

```
sudo yum install centos-release-scl
sudo yum install devtoolset-9
env PATH="/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/bin:${PATH}"
```

Switch to new devtoolset version:

```
scl enable devtoolset-9 -- bash
```

Check

```
gcc --version
```

After reboot you'll see gcc 4.8.5 again so you have to do `scl enable devtoolset-9 -- bash` after each reboot

Answer (score -15):

Command to install GCC and Development Tools on a CentOS / RHEL 7 server

Type the following yum command as root user:
`yum group install "Development Tools"`

OR
`sudo yum group install "Development Tools`

If above command failed, try:
`yum groupinstall "Development Tools`