# version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in file ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

Tags: gcc, libc

if anyone could give a beginner some help on gcc version issue?

I met the issue on `"version GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found"`. After I followed the link: [How to Install gcc 5.3 with yum on CentOS 7.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36327805/how-to-install-gcc-5-3-with-yum-on-centos-7-2)
I met extra issues as below:

```
scl enable devtoolset-7 bash
git: relocation error: libc.so.6: symbol _dl_starting_up, version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in file ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 with link time reference
```

Answer (score 18):

> if anyone could give a beginner some help on gcc version issue?

Your problem has *nothing* to do with any GCC versions.

> `git: relocation error: libc.so.6: symbol _dl_starting_up, ...`

This error most likely means that you are trying to use something *other* than the system `libc.so.6` (perhaps by pointing `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to directory that contains a copy of `libc.so.6` from a different system).

Don't do that: it doesn't work. Using alternate GLIBC version is possible, but complicated. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847179/multiple-glibc-libraries-on-a-single-host) provides some ways to do that.

Comment: It is false that it does not work. Several SDKs do that routinely in hundreds of production machines. GLIBC has versioned symbols, so you have graceful errors like the ones reported.

I do not downvote because the answer is mostly correct, except for the "Don't do that: it doesn't work."

Answer (score 5):

Solution is as follows:

1. Create a local installation path mirroring / (root path) and containing usr/lib64 and a symlink to usr/lib64 at the same level as usr
2. Compile and install GLibC locally (i.e. configure --prefix=/local/installation/path (/local/installation/path contains usr and lib64 symlink)
3. Install other necessary dependencies
4. Invoke your application by as follows

   ```
   /local/installation/path/usr/lib/ld-linux-${arch}.so.${version} \
     --library-path /local/installation/path/usr/lib:/local/installation/path/usr/lib64:... \
     Your-Bin-Name \
     Your-Bin-CLI-Options
   ```

   NOTE: Add additional paths as needed, separating each with a colon