# How can I install ASP.NET Core application on a hostgator linux shared hosting?

Tags: c#, linux, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have tried to install it, using the steps written by Hanselman https://www.hanselman.com/blog/RunningASPNETCoreOnGoDaddysCheapestSharedLinuxHostingDontTryThisAtHome.aspx.

But I end up with much more errors than he is describing on this post. Those are the steps I had followed:

1. Create an MyApp sample application using Visual Studio. See the image: 
   [App Created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZRC4.png)
2. Compile the project using Visual Studio. Then this command, to publish files:

   ```
   dotnet publish -r rhel.6-x64
   ```
3. Upload the files from the published folder to my Linux shared hosting site, see picture: [Files Uploaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXhoR.png)

   ```
   From: C:\MyApp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\rhel.6-x64\publish
   ```

   to the Linux shared hosting site public_http folder, of course using WinSCP.
4. Then got to my Shared Linux Cpanel and make enable my SSH connections
5. Open Putty log on to Linux Shared Hosting server, using my user name and password SSH.
6. Give all permits to the file: MyApp to make it executable, as mentioned on Hanselman's post.
7. When I execute it, using the instruction as mentioned on Hanselman's post.
8. First it is complaining for the library: libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt5.x86_64. 
   https://altlinux.pkgs.org/sisyphus/classic-x86_64/libstdc++6-8.2.1-alt5.x86_64.rpm.html
   I downloaded using wget and put into the folder netcoredeps. Fine.
9. Second it is complaining for lib64/libc.so.6 version glibc_2.18. I find this: glibc-core-2.27-alt8.x86_64. At https://altlinux.pkgs.org/sisyphus/classic-x86_64/glibc-core-2.27-alt8.x86_64.rpm.html. I downloaded using wget and put into the folder netcoredeps. Fine.
10. Then tried to run the app again with ./MyApp and getting:

    ```
    / relocation error: /home2/xxxx/public_html/netcoredeps/libc.so.6: symbol _dl_starting_up, version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in file ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 with link time reference
    ```

[image: Error Image]

This netcoredeps folder end up like this:

[image: How Ends The netcoredeps Folder]

Comment: Hi Eduardo. Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Your question is a bit unclear. It might help to edit it down to a specific error relating to which ever step you go to following the instructions you linked.

Comment: Hi @MikeS159 I did some change to make it clear. Regards.

Comment: @EduardoSantana Is there any error message that you see? I never run .net core on Linux, I use Windows here and it is working fine. You need to make sure that your hosting provider support .net core on Linux. Basically .net run well on Windows environment.

Comment: @MarkSpencer one of the main features of .net core is the hability to run almost any where. It can run in Linux, Mac and windows and  raspberry. Sometimes you have a shared Linux hosting for what ever reason, and you can run .net core on this like it is explained in the post that I mentioned by Hanselman. Please read this post so you understand the question more clearly. Thanks . https://www.hanselman.com/blog/RunningASPNETCoreOnGoDaddysCheapestSharedLinuxHostingDontTryThisAtHome.aspx

Comment: Can someone please give any comments on this?

Comment: Have you checked this answer? It talks about the same issue and links to an answer that may have what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245547/version-glibc-private-not-defined-in-file-ld-linux-x86-64-so-2

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is, if you have /lib in LD_LIBRARY_PATH or MIC_LD_LIBRARY_PATH, then if so remove it.

Comment: Hi @Gauravsa your answer is a bit unclear. Can you please be more specific?