# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'phalcon.so'

Tags: php, linux, centos, phalcon

I am trying to run phalcon in php but it seems from the errors that it cannot load it.

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'phalcon.so' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/phalcon.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/phalcon.so: undefined symbol: __builtin_saddl_overflow), /usr/lib64/php/modules/phalcon.so.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/phalcon.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0

I've tried all the solutions that are on the web but I cant solve it.
I already add the **extension=phalcon.so** in php.ini and also made a file zzzzz.ini which contains the same extension but it does not work.

Those are the solutions that I found on the web.

Can someone else help me to solve my problem ?

Thanks in advance

**Edit 1**

GCC Version: gcc (GCC) 7.3.1 20180303 (Red Hat 7.3.1-5)

Comment: Did you compile phalcon like this? https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/master/README.md#centosfedorarhel

Comment: @digijay yes I followed the instructions from that post

Comment: You have to use gcc >= 5.0, what version do you have installed? `gcc --version`

Comment: @digijay gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)

should i update ?

Comment: Yes, have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39731134

Comment: @digijay I updated but still the same problem (cant run phalcon)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, i resolved by upgrading GCC to >= 5.0 then recompiled Phalcon. For centOS 7

```
sudo yum install -y yum-utils centos-release-scl;
sudo yum -y --enablerepo=centos-sclo-rh-testing install devtoolset-7-gcc;
echo "source /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/enable" | sudo tee -a /etc/profile;
source /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/enable;
gcc --version;
```