# encountering ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode error when I try to install mysqlclient via pip

Tags: python

I'm unable to install the Python mysqlclient library via pip3 due to the following error

```
$ pip3.6 install mysqlclient
...
MySQLdb/_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_row_to_dict_cached’:
MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1340:5: error: ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode
     for (unsigned int i=0; i
```

The OS is CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908 (Core), the gcc version is shown below

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had to install a new gcc version, unfortunately the package is not present on the standard repositories, and I had to add the Software Collections repository to the system a detailed post on how to do that can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36327805/how-to-install-gcc-5-3-with-yum-on-centos-7-2).

```
    yum install centos-release-scl -y
    yum install devtoolset-7-gcc* -y
    scl enable devtoolset-7 bash
    pip3 install mysqlclient
```